# Unable to convert the result of count as integer

Tags: python, count

In the code in follow lines can be converted the result as integer. The code is :

```
import os, sys
import re
import urllib.request as urr
from urllib.parse   import quote
from urllib.request import urlopen
response=urr.urlopen('http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=%CF%85%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1'+quote('υγεια') )
pagea=print(re.findall("(?!\")http://archive.data.gov.gr/dataset?q=υγεια&page= (?=\")", str(response)))
pagea=response.read()
p1=pagea.count
p=int([p1]) #the problem is here

print(p)# and here


for i in range (1,p):
    
    
    f=open('C:\pagea.html',"wb")

    f.write(pagea)
    f.close()
    print(pagea)
```

In the follow code cant be converted pagea.count as number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having list , you can't convert it to int like that.

you can get length of list with `len`.

Or you can make for loop and do following:

```
counter = 0
for item in list:
   counter = counter +1
```

to use `int()` argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number